# The initialization of my playerCard does not work

Tags: ios, swift, debugging

I'm new to swift and I'm trying to make a simple card game where the player and computer draws a card and whoever has the largest card wins. But when I call my compareCards function, I got an error: constant 'playerCard' used before being initialized. I thought I already initialized playerCard so I'm wondering if someone could tell me what's wrong with my code? Thank you.

```
import Foundation
func randomInteger(upper: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(upper)))
}


enum Rank: Int{
    case two = 2,
    three,
    four, five,
    six,
    seven,
    eight,
    nine,
    ten,
    jack,
    queen,
    king,
    ace

    static func allValues() -> [Rank]{
        return [two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, jack, queen, king, ace]
    }
}

enum Suit: Int{
    case clubs = 1,
    diamonds,
    hearts,
    spades

    static func allValues() -> [Suit]{
        return [spades, hearts, diamonds, clubs]
    }
}

struct Card{
    var rank: Rank = .two
    var suit: Suit = .clubs

    init(rank: Rank, suit: Suit){
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
    }
}

class Deck{

    var deck: [Card] = []
    var rankArray: [Rank] = []
    var suitArray: [Suit] = []

    init(){
        rankArray = Rank.allValues()
        suitArray = Suit.allValues()

        for aRank in rankArray{
            for aSuit in suitArray{
                let aCard = Card(rank: aRank, suit: aSuit)
                deck.append(aCard)
            }
        }

    }

    func drawOne() -> Card?{
        if deck.count != 0{
            let randomCard = randomInteger(upper: deck.count)
            let aCard = deck[randomCard]
            deck.remove(at: randomCard)
            return aCard
        }
        else{
            return nil
        }
    } 
}

func compareCards(playerCard: Card, computerCard: Card) -> String{
    var isPlayerGreater: Bool = false

    if playerCard.rank != computerCard.rank{
        if playerCard.rank.rawValue > computerCard.rank.rawValue{
            isPlayerGreater = true
        }
    }

    if playerCard.suit.rawValue > computerCard.suit.rawValue{
        isPlayerGreater = true
    }

    if isPlayerGreater == true{
        return "The player won with the \(playerCard.rank) of \(playerCard.suit)!"
    }

    else{
        return "The computer won with the \(computerCard.rank) of \(computerCard.suit)!"
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

let playerCard: Card
let computerCard: Card

let aDeck = Deck()
if let aCard = aDeck.drawOne(){
    playerCard = Card(rank: aCard.rank, suit: aCard.suit)
}

if let aCard = aDeck.drawOne(){
    computerCard = Card(rank: aCard.rank, suit: aCard.suit)
}

var result: String = compareCards(playerCard: playerCard, computerCard: computerCard)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you didn't initialize. your darawOne() function is nullable and you set condition " if aDeck -> playercard = aDeck". what about if result == nil???
I change your last code to this:

```
let aDeck = Deck()
if let aCard = aDeck.drawOne(), let seCard = aDeck.drawOne(){
    let playerCard = Card(rank: aCard.rank, suit: aCard.suit)
    let computerCard = Card(rank: aCard.rank, suit: seCard.suit)

    let result: String = compareCards(playerCard: playerCard, computerCard: computerCard)
    print(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works well.

```
let aDeck = Deck()

if let playerCard = aDeck.drawOne(), let computerCard = aDeck.drawOne() {
    var result: String = compareCards(playerCard: playerCard, computerCard: computerCard)
    print(result)
}
```

Error was thrown by compiler because you have declared two non-optional constants but not initialised it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you must init `playerCard` and `computerCard` before using it. If your code will not pass `if let` statement your cards will not init.

Here you have two options atleast either provide a default value to your variables either mark them as force unwrapped so the compiler will ignore not inited state as you telling that you 100% sure variables will be at run time.

The second option will look next:

Replace your

```
let playerCard: Card
let computerCard: Card
```

With:

```
var playerCard: Card!
var computerCard: Card!
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to just declare `playerCard` and `computerCard` variable with `var` keyword instead of `let`

***You can use `let` when you know that once you assign a value to a variable, it doesn't change and with using `var` you can change the value to a variable.***

```
var playerCard: Card
var computerCard: Card

let aDeck = Deck()
if let aCard = aDeck.drawOne(){
    playerCard = Card(rank: aCard.rank, suit: aCard.suit) //you are assigning/changing the value here of playerCard variable.
}

if let aCard = aDeck.drawOne(){
    computerCard = Card(rank: aCard.rank, suit: aCard.suit) //you are assigning/changing the value here of playerCard variable.
}
```